# What part of speech is 'there'?

Tags: grammar

> When I read about the two famous grammar books - The Cambridge Grammar
>   of the English Language, A Comprehensive Grammar of the English
>   Language, I happened to across a very interesting sentence below.
>
> What are you doing in **there**? ([source](http://k.daum.net/qna/view.html?category_id=QNE001&qid=3ZHxb&q=A%20Comprehensive%20Grammar%20of%20the%20English%20Language&srchid=NKS3ZHxb))

The questioner wanted to know what part of speech is *there*,adverb or noun? Which is it?

Comment: Before you get too bogged down in adverbs, I recommend [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/) question on ELU. As McCawley says, it's a 'wastebasket' category - where you put everything that doesn't fit anywhere else.

Comment: @StoneyB, Thank you. When I first heard the category from prof. Lawler, it was very strange. Now I get some understanding.

Comment: @Listenever "Adverb" was a wastebasket category in traditional grammar.  In modern grammar "adverb" is usually better defined, with "particle" taking over the wastebasket role.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*There* in that sentence is adverb. It can be an exclamation as in "There, there, you must take all of this philosophically." but it is never a noun.

Comment: I might be convinced if the question were about "there" in "What are you doing **there**?". But isn't the question about "What are you doing **in** *there*?"

Answer (score 2):

The sentence ”What are you doing in there?” includes a preposition *in*. All prepositions have an object, which must be a noun. If *in* is a preposition, then there must be the object and a noun.

Comment: I agree with you that that "in" is a preposition, though I would rather say that that "there" is a pronoun rather than a noun.